# Python Selenium select from smart search drop down

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get historical prices from bse website by downloading individual csv files. I am using python and selenium with chrome driver.

The inputs are security name : One can enter the first few letters or code and select the name from the smart search box, then select the start and end dates and click submit. The data is rendered as a csv file which downloads when clicked.

I used the examples given and have tried the following method but it does not select the name which comes when the code is entered and the webpage gives an error to enter the to date.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

#browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser = webdriver.Chrome() #replace with .Firefox(), or with the browser of your choice
url = "http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/StockPrcHistori.aspx?flag=0&expandable=7"
browser.get(url) #navigate to the page

securitycode = browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GetQuote1_smartSearch") # code for security
startdt = browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFromDate") #start date form field
enddt = browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtToDate") #start date form field

select = Select(securitycode)
select.select_by_visible_text("500010")

#securitycode.send_keys("500010")
#startdt.send_keys("01/01/1991")
#enddt.send_keys("29/01/2018")

time.sleep(5)

#submitButton = browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit") 
#submitButton.click()
# now wait for the next page to be loaded
#time.sleep(10)
#browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn--link").click()
#time.sleep(10)
```

The commented section of the code is another attempt.

I saw the section on using select but that also does not work.

Comment: got the solution